# How do I send an email on a Google Sheet when certain cells change using the Apps Script?

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, google-apps-script

I created a script to send email on Google Sheet with the following conditions:

1. When the **Assign Email column** is filled in and the **Status column** changes to **In Progress**, then the notification will appear to send an email.
2. When the **Date Finished column** and the **Assign Email column** are filled in. Then **Status column** changes to In **Done** and the notification will appear to send an email.

But when the notification sends an email appears and I select the yes button, 
[image]
the email is not sent.

The script that I wrote like this :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var status = ss.getActiveCell();
var column = status.getColumn();
var row = status.getRow();
var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, 11).getValues();

function alert(){
  var response = Browser.msgBox('Email Notification', 'Are you sure to send this message?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (response == "yes") {
    return autoSendMail();
  }
}

function onEdit(){
  if (column == 8 && row > 1 && status.getValue() !== ''){
    alert();
  }
  else
  {
    if (column == 9 && row > 1 && status.getValue() !== ''){
      alert();
  }
}
}

function autoSendMail(){
  var ticketNumber = values[0][5];
  var subject = "No-Reply Messages TOURMap for Ticket Number#" + ticketNumber;
  var emailRecipient = values[0][1];
  var emailProjectLead = values[0][4];
  var emailAssigment = values[0][7];
  var options = emailProjectLead+","+emailAssigment;
  var message = values[0][9];
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailRecipient,
                     subject: subject,
                     htmlBody: message,
                     cc: options});
// Browser.msgBox(emailRecipient+","+subject+","+options+","+message);
// SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Email has been sent successfully", "Notification");
}
```

**I changed the script to :**

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var status = ss.getActiveCell();
  var column = status.getColumn();
  var row = status.getRow();
  var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, 11).getValues();
  var ticketNumber = values[0][5];
  var subject = "No-Reply Messages TOURMap for Ticket Number#" + ticketNumber;
  var emailRecipient = values[0][1];
  var emailProjectLead = values[0][4];
  var emailAssigment = values[0][7];
  var options = emailProjectLead+","+emailAssigment;
  var message = values[0][9];

  var response = Browser.msgBox('Email Notification', 'Are you sure to send this message?', Browser.Buttons.YES_NO);
  if (column == 8 && row > 1 && status.getValue() !== ''){
    if (response == "yes") {
    return MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailRecipient,
                       subject: subject,
                       htmlBody: message,
                       cc: options});
  };
  }
  else
  {
    if (column == 9 && row > 1 && status.getValue() !== ''){
      if (response == "yes") {
    return MailApp.sendEmail({to: emailRecipient,
                       subject: subject,
                       htmlBody: message,
                       cc: options});
  };
  }
}
}
```

This script does not work when the cell changes (there is no interaction and there is no error message). But when I run this script manually, it can work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I was surprised that your script had been largely changed. In this case, my answer cannot be resolving your issue. So I have to remove my answer. I apologize for this situation. By the way, I couldn't understand about your current issue. Because when the columns "H" and "I" are edited, each ``MailApp.sendEmail()`` is run. So how about confirming the each variables of ``{to: emailRecipient,subject: subject,htmlBody: message,cc: options}``?

Comment: my case seems similar to the one at this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163274/4920979

Comment: Based on the answer from the link I got them saying that the email cannot be sent via the onEdit function.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks for helping..